# React-native-ble characteristic write error : 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: data != nil'

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use [react-native-ble](https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/react-native-ble) and I had a first issue : **buffer is not defined**, so I added the [shim.js](https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/react-native-ble/blob/master/examples/eddystone_beacon_scanner/shim.js) before calling react-native-ble but I had this error :

```
[fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RNBLEQueue] Exception 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: data != nil' was thrown while invoking write on target RNBLE with params (
    "AA542816-1CD6-8FF8-2766-BCBF89A4A634",
    "4B48E81D-BFBD-4334-8CB5-1F941E00AA50",
    "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFF4",
    Samoud,
    1
)
```

Here is my code :

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      self._connectDevice(peripheral, id)
      .then((characteristic) => {
        // data = 'Samoud'
        characteristic.write(data, true, function(error) {
          if (error) reject(error);
          resolve(true);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });
```

Any idea how to fix this please ?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Data to be written must be a Buffer. You have passed string. Also I have found that if the 2nd argument is true then write is not successful.

Try this code:---

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  self._connectDevice(peripheral, id)
  .then((characteristic) => {
    // data = 'Samoud'
    characteristic.write(new Buffer('Samoud'), false, function(error) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      resolve(true);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```